# GODOT export to android to get a apk (release Keystore) FAILED

Tags: android, godot

I have spent countless hours on this and still not able to get an apk using the release keystore. To upload to the android store. I need to use the release keystore and the debug keystore won't work. I used this post to help me and used this command in cmd (windows) to generate the release keystore. I typed all the info they wanted and clicked return as I will be using the same password for the keystore.

Link: https://godotengine.org/qa/265/how-release-project-google-play-store-android-release-mode

Command: keytool -genkey -v -keystore release.keystore -alias yourKeyAlias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

I then go the Project > Export > Keystore. for Release row I attached the release keystore generated earlier. For Release User (2nd row) I put "yourKeyAlias". For Release Password (3rd row) I put the password I entered earlier.

I click "Export Project" and turn "Export with debug" to off. While exporting it crashes. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: It would be a great help to know which operating system you are running Godot engine in. If it is windows, There is usually a command window with a log output in it, What does that log file say? If on linux you may want to start godot from terminal as the erminal window will then contain the log output. 
Simply saying "it crashes" does not help.